# Placing a structure within a map container - or is there a different, more suitable way to store this type of data?

Tags: database, matlab, data-structures, containers

I have some data associated with several "labels" ('Jan','Feb','Mar', for example), and for each of these labels there are multiple data types (numeric arrays, strings, datetime, etc).

I would like to access the data by *specifying the label itself*, so I don't have to keep track of any integer indices. I have recently discovered Matlab [map containers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html), and tried to implement it in this case by using my "labels" as the *keys* in the map:

```matlab
keys = {'Jan','Feb','Mar'};
data_map = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','any');

% loop over keys and put some data in the map
for k = 1:length(keys)

    data_struct.prices = rand(1,5);   % create some dummy numbers
    data_struct.description = 'HIGH'; % create a dummy label

    % place the structure in the map at the relevant key
    data_map(keys{k}) = data_struct; 

    % delete ready for next iteration of the loop
    clear data_struct
end
```

This works okay, because

- the structure object is able to handle all the different data types without problem
- I can very compactly and nicely access my data without any integers using `data_map('Feb')`
  which yields:

```matlab
  struct with fields:

         prices: [0.9063 0.8797 0.8178 0.2607 0.5944]
    description: 'HIGH'
```

or `data_map('Feb').description` which yields: `'HIGH'`.

---

### My Problem

1) I feel like I am not using it in the correct way, because I have had to use the temporary structure `data_struct` inside the loop.

2) Additionally, later on I would now like to add an extra field to the structure associated with one of the keys, and would ideally do something like the following for example:

```matlab
data_map('Feb').temperature = rand(1,8);
```

This gives the following error:
**"Only one level of indexing is supported by a containers.Map."**

The only way I have been able to do it is to create a temporary structure, which is ugly and cumbersome:

```matlab
temp_struct = data_map('Feb');
temp_struct.temperature = rand(1,8);
data_map('Feb') = temp_struct;
clear temp_struct
disp( data_map('Feb').temperature )
```

Is there a better way to store this type of data?

Comment: For 1), I think you'll need a loop either way. For 2), you can use `setfield(data_map('Feb'),'temperature',1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`containers.Map` has a few nice properties, but I don’t think you are using those. You might as well use a simple struct.

You’d be able to index it using

```
data_map.Feb
data_map.('Feb')

data_map.Feb.description
data_map.('Feb').description
```

This would solve both of your problems:

Inside the loop:

```
data_map.(keys{k}).prices = rand(1,5);
data_map.(keys{k}).description = 'HIGH';
```

And after:

```
data_map.Feb.temperature = rand(1,8);
```

---

Consider also using a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html), your data organization seems like a table to me.

Comment: Great, thank you. I did not know that we can access a strcut using data_map.('Feb') syntax. I was only aware of doing something like an array and using data_map(k).prices, where k is an integer. Just out of interest, what are the "nice properties" of containers.map, and in what sort of situation should I begin to think about using it, when another data type wouldn't do the job? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, after reading a little, it seems to me that the biggest advantage of maps arises when you want to access data using some other key, that is not already defined as a variable name (i.e there is less restriction on the keys that you can use). Both struct and containers.map also seem to be able to store the same types of data. Are these fair take-away messages?

Comment: @teeeeee: Yes, indeed. A Map can use arbitrary keys (also numeric), a struct must have “keys” they are valid variable names. Also, a Map is a handle object, so modifying one inside a function modifies it also for the caller (i.e. instead of writing `data=change_data(data);` you can write `change_data(data);` (which I don’t particularly like, but many people seem to enjoy).

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, you can simplify things as follows:

```
keys = {'Jan','Feb','Mar'};
data_map = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','any');
n = size(keys,2);

% loop over keys and put some data in the map
for k = 1:n
    data_map(keys{k}) = struct('prices',rand(1,5),'description','HIGH');
end
```

For your second question, you can use:

```
setfield(data_map('Feb'),'temperature',rand(1,5))
```

Comment: +1 and thank you for the answer. This did fix the problem. I would have accepted either your answer or Cris' answer to be honest, but the other answer solved the problem and allowed me to just work with simple structures (without the extra complication of using containers.map). Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. No worries, I didn't suggest the struct because I thought you had already outweighed the differences between the two, and decided to go for a container :)